# Get key along with an value from list of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I get key & value object from a list of objects?

For instance:

```
var globalObjJSON = {
    "key1": {
        "firstName": "",
        "middleName": "",
        "lastName": "",
        "login": "",
        "photoID": ""
    },

    "key2" {
        "firstName": "Test",
        "middleName": "",
        "lastName": "",
        "login": "testthis@test.com",
        "photoID": ""
    },

    "key3" {
        "firstName": "First",
        "middleName": "",
        "lastName": "User",
        "login": "email@contactmethod.com",
        "photoID": ""
    }
}
```

where if i query for a particular key for example "key1" 
i expect the output have to be 
`{"key1":{"firstName":"","middleName":"","lastName":"","login":"","photoID":""}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, You are creating a new object with the key and value

```
function getKeyObj(key){
   var returnObj;
   if(!key){ 
     return returnObj;
   }
   var value = globalObjJSON[key];

   if(value) {
     returnObj = {};
     returnObj[key] = value
   }

  return returnObj;
```

}

Comment: it may not be `undefined` but I agree `globalObjJSON[key]` is better option

Comment: The above approach works fine , thanks that was helpful !.

Comment: But is there any more simpler way to do with some predefined way in javascript so that i can use it ? instead of writing a function ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it slighty lighter:
http://jsfiddle.net/95fvqrfL/3/

```
var getObjectFromJSON = function(key, jsonObj){
    if(jsonObj[key]){
        var obj = { key: jsonObj[key]};
        obj = JSON.stringify(obj).replace('key', key);
        return JSON.parse(obj);
    }
};
```

**(EDITED)**

Comment: Close, but the returned object would be `{"key": ...` instead of `{"key1": ...`